# How do change the arrow symbol of the contextmenu to another symbol?

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

I need to change the Symbol check arrow of the contextmenustrip to a another symbol as dot in below pic: How do i so that?

[image: this pic]

Comment: are there Any way to it?tell me more

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any simple, native way to do it. You probably have to reimplement the draw method of the menuitem. Maybe start looking this way:
[MenuItem.OwnerDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.ownerdraw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)